# 64 bit Twitter Framework for the app developed in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, xcode6

Earlier,I have created 32 bit xcode app,that include twitter API,but now,due to Apple's new requirement of an app to be 64 bit,I updated xcode to xcode 6.1 and ios 8.1 version,and made changes in the build settings...

```
Architectures:Standard Architecture(arm7,arm64)
Valid Architectures:armv7 armv7s arm64
```

But,now the error arises i.e.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAConsumer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OADataFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OARequestParameter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I think,the above error means I'll have to update the twitter API as 64 bit support.But,I am not getting latest version of twitter API.

Can,anyone tell I will have update twitter API or will have to do another thing...??Where I can find the latest version of twitter API,and how to update 32 bit frameworks and API into 64 bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?I am facingsame issue

Comment: @KrishnaVerma did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `i386 x86_64` to your valid architectures.

**Valid Architectures :** armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64

i386 -> 32 bit simulator 
x86_64 -> 64/32 bit simulator

Comment: Hi : Maheswaran, I am facing the same issue, I tried your solution but didnt work is there any other alternative for this?